when you submit a non-provisional that claims a provisional that already has everything set up, what do you include in the non-provisional
In the provisional application that I filed, most of everything is already there and I am satisfied with it.
For the non-provisional, I merely want to add a couple of more paragraphs that merely tout or further market the usefulness and versatility of the invention.
When I submit the non-provisional, what do I submit that can contain the above two paragraphs?


For the non-provisional, I merely want to add a couple of more paragraphs that merely tout or further market the usefulness and versatility of the invention.

Utility is usually a low bar - as long as one has treated utility at all it should be fine on that front.
Whenever you add something in a later filing it opens a line of attack for an opponent to argue that whatever you added wasn't sufficiently there in the earlier filing. Such an argument won't always work but you should be aware that there are cons to adding things in the non-provisional.
In other words, this is a case in which one should check to make sure it's busted before fixing it.

When I submit the non-provisional, what do I submit that can contain the above two paragraphs?

You would submit a complete application; i.e., a copy of your provisional with the desired paragraphs added. Don't forget to add the benefit claim in the ADS.

Make the nonprovisional as good as you can regardless of what changes you are making from the provisional. It will be examined and its claims and the support of its claims in its specification are what matters most. The provisional has value only to eliminate cited, intervening prior art.
A very high percent of provisionals play no part in the future of the actual prosecution. It would be a mistake to impair the quality of a non-provisional by viewing it as an edit of the provisional. This is especially true in the case of a pro se provisional or when significant work on the invention has occurred between the two applications.
It can make sense to have some fall back claims that are clearly supported by the provisional, assuming it even possible.
If an inventor drafts their own provisional and then goes to a patent practitioner for the non provisional they will find their provisional does not form a basis for the professional’s work. If they try to have the professional create an application that takes this issue into consideration they will not get a positive response.
Separately, hyping the benefits is a bad idea. It does nothing good, can hurt if not done carefully and makes the application look amateurish.

"The provisional has value only to eliminate cited, intervening prior art." Agreed, but I think adding clarifications (especially to the subject matter) can erode this elimination ability as it can introduce doubt that later presented claims were originally supported. So I do not think it is a good idea to make edits "regardless" of the changes being introduced; there is a balance to be struck.

I made some edits prompted by this comment.
